# .Net Remoting call delay

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

Our application calls, the following remoting call at 20ms.

```
void getAllBlockValues(out int[] ids, out byte[][] values)
```

Normally it takes 2-4 ms to return the call. But in some cases, the call takes more than 30ms. The server logs shows that the call received at the server side only after 20ms. The server and client are running in the same machine.

It looks like the .Net remoting layer is delaying the call.

How can I Identify the cause of the issue?

Is there any tools available to detect performance bottleneck of remoting calls(where they are blocking)?

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem? Its reason or any tools for detecting the problem. In our case we have delay for method calls using IP address. But using localhost remote method calls are executed with no delay.

Answer (score 0):

Following link contains microsoft guidance on improving remoting performance,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998565.aspx

If you are looking of IPC and it is always in same machine use IPC Channels, it will give better results